# WCF Rest Service

Tags: wcf, service

I am developing rest wcf service using linq to SQL. I am very new to wcf services. The problem I am facing is my web service output xml sorts my tags in ascending order and I don't want that can anybody give me some suggestions why do the web service sorts the tags in alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serializing members in alphabetical order is [default behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx) of `DataContractSerializer`. If you want different order you must set `Order` in `DataMember` attribute for every property.

Comment: so how do set order of that ?

Comment: i am returning an array so my xml output contains root element and inside it all other tags as output...so can we ignore the root node not to display in the output?

Comment: No that is not possible with this type of serialization. Moreover valid xml must have single root.

Comment: any other way can we achieve this ?